# Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor$Impl

Tags: android, gradle

When Android studio does Gradle sync, it has the following error message:

> Gradle "MyApplication2" project refresh failed
>
> Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor$Impl

After searching, still cannot get rid of it. Could you help? Thanks!

**My project build.grade:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My module build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
    model {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion = 23
            buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
            defaultConfig.with {
                applicationId = "SamplePlayer"
                minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
                targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
                versionCode = 1
                versionName = "1.0"
                ndk {
                    moduleName "SamplePlayer" 
                }
            }
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                    resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                    aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                    renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
                    jni.srcDirs = []
                }
            }
            task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
                commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/jni').absolutePath
            }
            tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
            }
            android.lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: '../Jar', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
```

**My other module build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
    model {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion = 23
            buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
            defaultConfig.with {
                applicationId = "com.example.cfcalex.myapplication2"
                minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
                targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
                versionCode = 1
                versionName = "1.0"
            }
        }
        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    }
```